# How can I get back to my Mac side?

Tags: backup, time-machine, bootcamp, partition

Probably not the right/good title, I admit.

Accidentally quit bootcamp while it was deleting Windows partition to make new one or while it was making new one after deleting previous partition. Restarted comp manually for other reason and unexpectedly got restarted into WINSTALL usb drive. Unable to get back to Mac side since then. Is my only option to do a fresh OS X install? I obv don’t want to lose everything.

-No start up disks present

-Can’t install Win 10

-Tried NVRAM and PRAM reset

-Couldn’t remove/reformat Windows partition

-Windows partition named disk0s6 doesn’t appear on left side anymore

-Can’t mount the actual Mac partition which is disk0s1

-Tried verifying and repairing all

-Can’t use TimeMachine backups - get “No Time Machine backups were found” after selecting the 
backup to use

[image: Disk Utility Pic 1/3]
[image: Disk Utility Pic 2/3]
[image: Disk Utility Pic 3/3]

Comment: If possible, open a command prompt window and post the output from the commands `diskutil list /dev/disk0`, `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`.

Answer (score 1):

are you able to see the mac disk via the terminal when you are in recovery mode?

it should be in /Volumes/ directory.